# Leiningen > 2.8.1 and Cursive?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, leiningen, cursive

Does Cursive support Leiningen at versions above 2.8.1? If so, how do I make Cursive aware of a newer version? I am currently on 2.8.3 - with no standalone.jar.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Posted to Cursive email group:  cursive@googlegroups.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just released a 1.8.1-eap3 which includes support for recent lein versions. They haven't received the extensive testing that I like to give new lein versions though (the integration is very brittle), so please report any issues in the [tracker](https://github.com/cursive-ide/cursive/issues). Assuming there are no serious problems I'll try to get this into a stable build soon.

If you're not currently set up to use EAP versions, instructions for how to do so are [here](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/index.html#eap).

Comment: Thank you for updating and for your product. I enjoy using it. I've updated to eap3 and will watch for issues. As an aside - I also appreciate your support for Deps. I have been using it lately in place of Leiningen for dependency and classpath management and I prefer it. Thanks for supporting.

Comment: Added 3/14/19: Could you please add Leiningen 2.9.1? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting because it helped me discover an issue with my own installation of Leiningen.

Version 2.8.2 of Leiningen has a breaking change to use 0.5.0 of nREPL instead of tools.nrepl 0.2.13 previously. I’m guessing this requires a code change that the author of Cursive is not yet ready to release. This also affects other libraries that have a dependency on nREPL such as piggieback.

I ended up downloading a local copy of 2.8.1 into my project because I couldn’t downgrade my brew installed version from 2.9.0.